# Heroku addon - programmatically create a deployhook

Tags: heroku

When I implement a custom Herku Addon, is it possible for it to programmatically add a deploy hook to the application?
I.e. say my programmers always deploy their Heroku apps with:

```
> heroku addons:add myCompanyAddon
> heroku addons:add deployhook:http; url="http://mycompany.com"
```

I'd prefer it if my programmers could just print a single line:

```
> heroku addons:add myCompanyAddon
```

And mycompanyAddon would internally execute the 2nd line of adding the deployhook.
I thought it should probably be possible, since 'deployhook' is an addon by itself, which does exactly what I wanted...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the platform API in order to programmatically add add-ons in this way. You can find details about adding addons here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#add-on-create